# How to create a multi-homed Docker container from command-line?

Tags: docker, mac-address, multi-homed

How do I create 2 NICs in a Docker container, each having a different MAC address, from outside of the container, when the container is created / spawned off for the first time?

That is, using the host's command-line interface and not that of the OS running in the container.

If I use `--mac-address=...` twice, only the second value is accepted resulting in a single-homed container.

Comment: Just curious; what are you doing that requires two different MACs in a docker container?

Comment: I have a legacy server application, whose source code I don't control nor have access to, that I'm trying to dockerize, that needs the presence of 2 NICs: 1 NIC it uses to tie its license to, and the other NIC it uses to communicate with database etc :-(